# How would I autofill code from sms into 6 UITextfields containing 1 digit each

Tags: ios, uikit

How would I autofill code from sms into 6 UITextfields containing 1 digit each?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to assign a tag to each of `UITextfield` like below if you have an array of `UITextfields`.

```
for i in 1 ... textFields.count {
    textFields[i].tag = i
    textFields[i].delegate = self
    textFields[i].textContentType = .oneTimeCode
}
```

After that, you have to use one of the `UITextfield` delegates method `shouldChangeCharactersIn`.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
     if string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).count != 0 {
         textField.text = string
         if textField.tag < textFields.count {
             let next = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1)
             next?.becomeFirstResponder()
         } else if textField.tag == textFields.count {
             textField.resignFirstResponder()
         }
     } else if string.count == 0 { // is backspace
         textField.text = ""
     }
        
     return false
 }
```

If you need an example and the best solution for this scenario, I would highly recommend my own Github repo: https://github.com/Datt1994/DPOTPView